# ServiceHostFactory is not being invoked

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I got a ASP.Net hosted service host:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="LongTermStorage.WebService.LongTermStorageService" 
    Factory="LongTermStorage.WebService.SteelServiceHostFactory"
    CodeBehind="LongTermStorageService.svc.cs" %>
```

`SteelServiceHostFactory` is not being invoked and I do not get any errors.

Factory:

```
public class SteelServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        return new SteelServiceHost(SteelWcfApplication.InstanceProvider, serviceType, baseAddresses);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if I switch from Cassini (development web server) to IIS.